# How do I make it so void OnCollisionEnter() applies to every instantiated object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I make it so that this line of code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

applies to every instantiated object?

Because only some of them but not all of the instantiated objects destroy themselves.

[PS:] How I want it to be:

Bullet is shot when that bullet collides with another entity it destroys itself and not all of them, I added this `PS` to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question sounds ambiguous, but I will try my best to answer that. 
You can make a separate script for destroying using "OnCollisionEnter" and attach it to your bullet prefab. 
Lets say, you created a script called "Destroy" and added following line of code in the class

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Then attach this script to your prefab called bullet. Now whenever you instantiated a bullet, this script will be attached to that bullet, and as soon as it hits another game object it will destroy itself. If you need to destroy any specific object with that bullet, then you can use tags to do that, something like this

```
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
        if(collision.gameobject.tag=="enemy")
            Destroy(collision.gameobject);      //to destroy enemy
        Destroy(gameobject);                    //to destroy bullet
     }
```

And if you want to destroy all of instantiated gameobject then you shoud store these game objects in array and run a loop into "OnCollisionEnter" to destroy them all together.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want to have your bullets destroy themselves *and* the object they hit. If so, it would be something like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    // destroy the GameObject with which the bullet collided, before destroying the bullet
    Destroy(collision.gameObject);  
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Comment: _"Bullet is shot when that bullet collides with another entity **it destroys itself** and not all of them, I added this PS to be more specific."_ so, no

Comment: @Kyle I obviously didn't understand the question then!